# HTTP Error 406 on Python Web scraper copy from Python All in One for Dummies

Tags: python, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, anaconda3

Afternoon all,

I'm following Python All In One for Dummies and have come to the chapter on web-scraping. I'm trying to interact with the website they designed specifically for this chapter, but keep getting an "HTTP Error 406" on all my requests. The initial "Open a page and get a response had the same issue till I pointed it at Google, so decided it was that webpage at fault.
Here's my code:

```
# get request module from URL lib
from urllib import request
# Get Beautiful Soup to help with the scraped data
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# sample page for practice
page_url = 'https://alansimpson.me/python/scrape_sample.html'

# open that page:
rawpage = request.urlopen(page_url)

#make a BS object from the html page
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage, 'html5lib')

# isolate the content block
content = soup.article

# create an empty list for dictionary items
links_list = []

#loop through all the links in the article
for link in content.find_all('a'):
    try:
        url = link.get('href')
        img = link.img.get('src')
        text = link.span.text

        links_list[{'url':url, 'img':img, 'text':text}]
    except AttributeError:
        pass

print(links_list)
```

and this is the output in the console:

```
(base) youngdad33@penguin:~/Python/AIO Python$ /usr/bin/python3 "/home/youngdad33/Python/AIO Python/webscrapper.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/youngdad33/Python/AIO Python/webscrapper.py", line 10, in <module>
    rawpage = request.urlopen(page_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable
```

I gather the most important line is the bottom one "HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable", which with a bit of digging I understand to mean my request headers aren't being accepted.

So how do I get this working? I'm using VS Code on a Chromebook using Linux Debian on Anaconda 3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject user-agent as follows:

```
# get request module from URL lib
import requests
# Get Beautiful Soup to help with the scraped data
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# sample page for practice
page_url = 'https://alansimpson.me/python/scrape_sample.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}
# open that page:
rawpage = requests.get(page_url,headers=headers)

#make a BS object from the html page
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')

# isolate the content block
content = soup.article

# create an empty list for dictionary items
links_list = []

#loop through all the links in the article
for link in content.find_all('a'):
    try:
        url = link.get('href')
        img = link.img.get('src')
        text = link.span.text

        links_list.append([{'url':url, 'img':img, 'text':text}])
    except AttributeError:
        pass

print(links_list)
```

## Output

```
[[{'url': 'http://www.sixthresearcher.com/python-3-reference-cheat-sheet-for-beginners/', 'img': '../datascience/python/basics/basics256.jpg', 'text': 'Basics'}], [{'url': 
'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/beginner/', 'img': '../datascience/python/beginner/beginner256.jpg', 'text': 'Beginner'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/justbasics/', 'img': '../datascience/python/justbasics/justbasics256.jpg', 'text': 'Just the Basics'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/cheatography/', 'img': '../datascience/python/cheatography/cheatography256.jpg', 'text': 'Cheatography'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/dataquest/', 'img': '../datascience/python/dataquest/dataquest256.jpg', 'text': 'Dataquest'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/essentials/', 'img': '../datascience/python/essentials/essentials256.jpg', 'text': 'Essentials'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/memento/', 'img': '../datascience/python/memento/memento256.jpg', 'text': 'Memento'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/syntax/', 'img': '../datascience/python/syntax/syntax256.jpg', 'text': 'Syntax'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/classes/', 'img': '../datascience/python/classes/classes256.jpg', 'text': 'Classes'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/dictionaries/', 'img': '../datascience/python/dictionaries/dictionaries256.jpg', 'text': 'Dictionaries'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/functions/', 'img': '../datascience/python/functions/functions256.jpg', 'text': 'Functions'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/ifwhile/', 'img': '../datascience/python/ifwhile/ifwhile256.jpg', 'text': 'If & While Loops'}], [{'url': 'https://alansimpson.me/datascience/python/lists/', 'img': '../datascience/python/lists/lists256.jpg', 'text': 'Lists'}]]
```